# "Косяк крилю" - це правильно?

Tags: значення-слів, росіянізм, відповідник

СУМ-20 каже, що косяк  - то скупчення риби під час нересту або розмовне зграя. Криль - не риба, а контекст не розмовний. Якщо "косяк" не підходить, то чим замінити в тексті? Табун?

Comment: Схоже, що косяк це група риб, що узгоджено рухаються в якомусь напрямку. Також, здається, як називати скупчення криля залежить від щільності такого скупчення.

Answer (score 2):

### Скупчення крилю

> [КРИЛЬ](https://uk.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C) — це планктонні морські рачки, що створюють **промислові
> скупчення** в поверхневих шарах води помірних і високих широт океанів
> обох півкуль.

На відміну від рою чи зграї, нектонні ракоподібні рухаються в товщі води хаотично, незалежно одне від одного.

Comment: Спочатку мене взяли сумніви, бо сама по собі «Вікіпедія» — не дуже надійне джерело, якщо вона не посилається на щось. Але з іншого боку подібне бачимо на сайті Державного агентства меліорації та рибного господарства України — на сторінці [«Про результаты XXXIII сесії ККАМЛР» від 05.12.2014](https://darg.gov.ua/_pro_rezuljtaty_xxxiii_sesiji_0_1_0_1702_1.html): «Сума відсотків перевищує 100%, оскільки враховується, що строк ефективної роботи в окремих районах буде відрізнятись (в залежності від термінів, коли море замерзне, чи утворяться скупчення криля тощо)» (хоча грамотність там не 100%).

Comment: @Sasha Погоджуюся з вашою думкою. Вікіпедія - це не професійний тлумачний словник. Втім, на відміну від урядових порталів, Вікі-спільнота хоча б час від часу перевіряє статті і виправляє помилки.

Comment: Так, згоден. І там, і там є плюси й мінуси. (От тільки тепер помітив «Про результат**ы**». А раніше кинулася вічі форма «криля» (замість словникового  «крилю»).)

Answer (score 1):

На жаль, не можу підкріпити відповідь надійним посиланням на україномовний ресурс, але це **рій** (swarm).

Один за варіантів перекладу на [e2u](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=swarm&dicts=all&highlight=on&filter_lines=on) це рій:

> swarm [swɔ:m] n
>
> 1. юрба, юрма, натовп;
> 2. *рій бджіл;*
> 3. купа, маса, сила-силенна;
>
> бджолин||ий, бджоляний bees, bee (attr.);
>
> - ...
> - ~ий рій swarm of bees;

Англомовна вікі-стаття [поведінка рою](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_behaviour#Krill) (англ. *swarm behaviour*), має розділ про криль (тут я взяв на себе сміливість перекласти *swarm* як *рій*):

> Більшість крилю, маленьки креветкоподібні ракоподібні, утворюють великі рої, що іноді сягають густини 10,000–60,000 осіб на кубичний метр. Роїння це захисний механізм, що заплутує менших хижаків, які б хотіли вибирати криль по поштучно. Найбільші рої видно з космосу і їх можна відстежити за допомогою супутника. Один рій, що ми його спостерігали, покривав площу в 450 квадратних кілометрів і сягав глибини в 200 метрів. Кількістно його оцінили в 2 мільйони тон крилю. Недавні дослідження показали, що криль не просто пасивно дрейфує в цих течіях, але змінює їх. Зазвичай криль виконує добову прямовисну міграцію. Рухаючись прямовисно крізь океан 12-годинними циклами, рій відіграє головну ролі в змішуванні глибших, поживнобагатших вод із поживнобіднішими поверхневими водами. Донедавна припускалось, що вони проводять день на більших глибинах, а вночі підіймають до поверхні. Було з'ясовано, що що глибше вони спускаються, то сильніше вони зменшують свою діяльність, вочевидь, щоб зменшити кількість зустрічей з хижаками і зберегти енергію.
>
> ... У 2012, Ґандомі і Алаві представили щось, що скидається на успішний стохастичний алгоритм для моделювання поведінки роїв крилю. Алгоритм покладається на три основні чинники «(i) *рух спричинений присутністю інших особин* (ii) діяльність з добування корму (iii) випадкову дифузію.»

Станом на 2009 [вчені не знали](https://phys.org/news/2009-10-krill-superswarm-formation.html) як криль утворює рої. Але рої утворюються і рухаються із течією. Якщо подивитись на сарану щодо якої часто використовують слово *рій*, то незрозуміло чому криль на заслуговує на нього, адже сарана утворює рої несвідомо, а від швидкого розмноження і летить із повітряною течією, а кріль з водною.

Comment: Дякую за відповідь. Скажіть, будь ласка, а десь є приклади "рою крилю"? Я бачу "рій бджіл", але хіба криль — це комаха?

Comment: @P.Vowk ні, але в англійській використовують swarm щодо тих і тих.

Comment: Спочатку я був погодився з цією відповіддю. Але зараз вона вже не здається мені обґрунтованою: з того, що англійське _swarm_ застосовують до комах та до крилю і у випадку комах його перекладають як _рій_, необов'язково випливає, що у випадку крилю _swarm_ теж треба перекладати як _рій_.

Comment: За цією логікою "pack of wolves" треба перекладати як "пачка вовків"? В англійській мові багато означень груп тварин які не мають окремого відповідника в українській.

Comment: @Artemix Не зовсім зрозумів ваш приклад, бо я не знаю перекладів інших *pack of smth*, які б перекладались як *пачка чогось*. Все ж мені здається, що ви маєте на увазі, що якщо ми маємо *swarm of bees* як *рій бджіл*, то вважати це аргументом за переклад *swarm of krill* як *рій крилю* це неправильна логіка, так?

Comment: @Artemix ваша аналогія неправильна, бо таким чином ви відмовляєте в існуванні всім конструкціям, які в українській співпадають з дослівним перекладом

Comment: Якщо конструкція існує і співпадає із українською то тут нема нічого "забороненого" чи неправильного, але якщо існування конструкції доводиться лише можливістю дослівного перекладу з англійської, то це вже не працює. Ось наприклад українське слово "стадо". Якби ми його не знали у нас були б такі варіанти: train/caravan/flock of camels, string/stud of horses, team of oxen, herd/mob of deer, drove of bullocks, sounder of wild boar.

Answer (score 1):

Якщо відштовхувати ся від тої ж Вікіпедії, що була згадана тут, то:

- [*зграя*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%8F) наводе до прикладу *антарктичний криль*;
- [*евфавзієві*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D1%83%D1%84%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D1%96%D1%94%D0%B2%D1%96), що входе в той ж надряд *Eucarida*, вказує про *невеликі креветки, що живуть в зграях*.

Далї я вже не лїз, бо вже зрозуміло, що *крилї* ± дещо споріднені з *креветками*, котрі розповсюдженїші в літературї, тож можна шукати в тому напрямі. Таким чином надибав на [Держрибагентстві](//darg.gov.ua/files/6/zbirnyk16.pdf) таке:

> За цей час, навіть при відносно невисокій щільності *зграйок*
> креветок, вони в процесі переміщення уздовж берега неминуче
> потрапляють у зону облову цих знарядь.

В побутї навколотваринних осїдках теж вживано:

- [Тетра](http://tvaryny.pp.ua/536-prsnovodna-krevetka-enciklopedya-tvarin.html): *…можна виділити труднощі з розведенням, необхідність утримувати великими **зграйками** та їх здатність відбирати корм у риб* [про креветку амано];
- [Поради.co.ua](https://porady.co.ua/sum-sn-st-krevetok-z-ribkami-v-akvar-um-24-foto-bud-akvar-umnih-rib-mozhna-poseliti-dlya-sp-l-nogo-utrimannya-z-kim-krevetki-ne-vzhivayut-sya/): *…хижі риби не нападають на **зграї** креветок, а виловлюють їх поодинці*;
- [Тексти](//texty.org.ua/articles/87331): *Ліхтариком світиш у воду і приманюєш **зграї** креветок*;
- ітд.

Тож якщо загалом і за декотрим узусом, то можна вживати **зграя**.

Радю також звернути увагу на [*herd of whales — стадо китів*](/a/2536/585), де  були спроби розглянути декотрі тямки.

Comment: Здається, що зграя це про скупчення, в якому можна виокремити окремих особин, а рій більше про скупчення, в якому окремих учасників не видно чи майже не видно. Тобто, гадаю, що зграєю можна назвати маленьке скупчення зазвичай дорослого крилю, в якому можна розпізнати окремих учасників.